# Select odd elements except the first-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have div elements like this

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the first-child but I have a css like this

```
#container #content:nth-child(odd) .arrow {
    background: red;
}
#container #content:nth-child(even) .arrow {
    background: green;
}
#container #content:first-child .arrow {
    background: pink;
}
```

But then the first-child is color red because first child is an odd number.

I tried using this and I don't know if it's going to work and it didn't

```
#container #content:nth-child(odd):not(:first-child) .arrow {
    background: red;
}
```

But then, the first div's arrow is still red.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Way you have done is working for me..http://jsfiddle.net/PLUJa/

Comment: Why do you have several elements with the same ID?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`:nth(odd)` is just a shortcut for `:nth(2n+1)`, if memory serves, so I'd think `:nth(2n+3)` might work.

Comment: Indeed, and to be clear, `:nth-child(2n+3)` would substitute `:nth-child(odd):not(:first-child)`.

Comment: Yes, but in regards of the readability, the second solution could be the better choice. Or are there any hard facts that I miss? Like memory or runtime, that would make the first one the better solution?

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
#container #content:first-child .arrow {
    background: pink!important;
}
```

That gives priority to that value

Regards!

Comment: Using `!important` is a no-no unless you have a very good reason to do so.

Comment: What do you mean I didn't?
When two or more classes match the same element, !important gives priority to that declaration

Comment: That's what it does, sure, but that alone is not a good reason to use it because in the majority of cases there is a better solution.